# Power of a statistical test

Tags: statistics

I was working on the following problem:

Consider two probability density functions on $[0,1]: f_0(x) = 1$, and $f_1(x) = 2x$. Among all tests of the null hypothesis $H_0: X \sim f_0(x)$ versus the alternative $X \sim f_1(x)$, with significance level $\alpha = 0.1$, how large can the power possibly be?

I think we need to begin by looking at an arbitrary test with significance level $\alpha = 0.1$ but I am having a hard time doing this. I am not even sure this is the direction we want to head in so I was hoping to get some hints regarding this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{\Gamma_0, \Gamma_1\}$ be a partition of $[0,1]$ into (measurable) sets and the decision rule be that hypothesis $H_i$ is true if the observation $X$ belongs to
$\Gamma_i$.  Then, the false alarm probability is 
$$\alpha = \int_{\Gamma_1} f_0(x)\,\mathrm dx = 0.1$$ while the power of the
test is
$$\beta = \int_{\Gamma_1} f_1(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$
Now,since $f_0(x)$ is the uniform density, we know that the total "length"
of the set $\Gamma_1$ is $0.1$ and so the question is

> What should we choose $\Gamma_1$ to be so as to *maximize* 
>   $\displaystyle \int_{\Gamma_1} f_1(x)\,\mathrm dx$?

*Sketching* the shape of the density $f_1(x)$ might reveal the answer
to you in a flash, and then you can write down a more formal way
of getting to it if you like.